# How to query single column as single result value with spring-data-jpa?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The Entity class:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
  var id: Int?
  var code: String
  ...
}
```

Expected method: (failed)

```
interface MyEntityJpaRepository : JpaRepository<MyEntity, Int> {
  fun getFirstCodeByCodeStartingWithOrderByCodeDesc(codePrefix: String) : String
}
```

The wanted result:

```
select code from MyEntity where code like '20180101_%' order by code desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a working solution, but it is not so perfect.

The defination:

```
interface MyEntityJpaRepository : JpaRepository<MyEntity, Int> {
  @Query("select code from MyEntity where code like ?1% order by code desc")
  fun getMaxCode(codePrefix: String, pageable: Pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1)): List<String>
}
```

The Usage:

```
val code = repository.getMaxCode(codePrefix = "20180101_").firstOrNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`findFirstByCodeLike(String Code);`
This will fetch the whole entity class and you can select `code` from it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5462308/rj-hwang If you have the entity class, you can use the getters `getCode()`  to get the `code`

Comment: I don't have the whole entity instance, just want to query code only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you want is possible with Spring Data JPA using only method definitions. You need to use the `@Query` annotation and write your query in there if you need a specific field, or get the whole entity and get the code from it with a getter like Jibin TJ said.